# getting error while clicking on profiles sonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

I am getting error while clicking on profile in sonarQube. The error is 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSlyL.png)

In the logs, i am seeing these entries

```
2016.01.12 02:35:20 ERROR [o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade]  Fail to render: http://sonarci.corelogic.net/profiles
```

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
        On line #17 of app/views/profiles/index.html.erb

```
14: </ul>
15: </div>
16: <%
17: Api::Utils.insensitive_sort(languages){|l| l.getName()}.each do |language|
18: default_profile = Internal.quality_profiles.defaultProfile(language.getKey())
19: %>
20: <div class="line-block">

app/views/profiles/index.html.erb:17
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:265:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:348:in `_render_with_layout'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:346:in `_render_with_layout'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:262:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1252:in `render_for_file'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:936:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render_with_benchmark'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render_with_benchmark'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1328:in `default_render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1334:in `perform_action'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_with_filters'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_with_benchmark'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_with_benchmark'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_with_rescue'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in `perform_action_with_flash'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2235:in `send'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_with_filters'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:450:in `call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:85:in `dispatch'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in `call'
gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
file:lib/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/session_store.rb:70:in `context'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
file:lib/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:34:in `serve_rails'
file:lib/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:39:in `call'
file:lib/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:22:in `call'
```

If anyone has come across this or know about this, please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: SonarQube version ? Plugins installed ? Do you get this error after installing a specific plugin ?

Comment: Sonar version is 4.2. The plugins installed are below